# Uncaught TypeError : Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList') what's wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So, basically the thing is that I am creating a responsive header navbar component in ReactJs and the problem is that I am using variable.classList.toggle after a maximum width of the screen is reached to animate the restyled navbar and it's working sometime but most of the time the moment I click it it returns an error in the console that "Header.jsx:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')" and the desired toggle animation just doesn't happen,

```
import "./header.css";
import React from "react";

const menu = document.querySelector(".menu-icon");
  const navbar = document.querySelector(".ul");
  
  const menue = () => {
    menu.classList.toggle("bx-x");
    navbar.classList.toggle("open");
  };

function Header() {
  return (
    <nav>
      <div className="navbar">
        <div className="logo">
          <img src="../../public/images/logo.svg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <ul className="ul">
          <li>
            <a href="\">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="\">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="\">Classes</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="\">Trainers</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="\">News</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="\">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="btn">
        <button>Book Class</button>
      </div>
      <div className="menu">
        <i className="ri-menu-line menu-icon" onClick={menue}></i>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

here is the jsx code and here is the css,

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
nav{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 28px 12%;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
}

ul{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    gap: 10px;
}

nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 0.7rem;
    color: black;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px 5px;
}

nav ul li a::after{
    content: "";
    background-color: #a1f65e;
    height: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -5px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transform: scale(0, 1);
}

nav ul li a:hover::after{
    transform: scale(1,1);
}

.logo img{
    width: 13vw;
}

.btn button{
    padding: 0.8rem;
    width: 10vw;
    border: none;
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    margin-left: 2rem;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.btn button:hover{
    background: #dcdcdc;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn button:active{
    transform: scale(0.7);
}

nav .menu i{
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 1100px){
    nav{
        justify-content: space-between;
        transition: 0.2s;
        padding: 28px 30px;
    }
    .btn button{
        font-size: 0.7rem;
        width: 20vw;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 800px){
    .btn button{
        font-size: 0.5rem;
    }
    nav .menu i{
        display: block;
        margin-left: 10px;
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        font-weight: 100;
        transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
    }
    nav .menu i:hover{
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    nav .menu i:active{
        transform: scale(0.7);
        cursor: pointer;
    }


    nav ul{
        position: absolute;
        top: 90%;
        right: -100%;
        width: 35vw;
        height: 11rem;
        background-color: #a1f65e;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: flex-start;
        flex-direction: column;
        z-index: 101;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
        color: white;
    }

    .logo img{
        width: 30vw;
    }

    nav ul li a{
        display: block;
        margin: 0.1rem 0;
        padding: 0px 20px;
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        transition: 0.5s all ease;
    }
    nav ul li a:hover{
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translateY(5px);
    }

    nav ul.open{
        right: 2%;
    }
}
```

I was expecting it toggle on clicking the menu icon but it isn't toggling and returning the following error :Header.jsx:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')

Comment: `menu` and `navbar` are undefined because they are set before the elements you associate with them are inserted into the DOM by React.

Comment: very common mistake, you see this question on SO at least daily

Answer (score 0):

That is not how you do things in ReactJS (getting a reference to an Element using `document.querySelector`).

The usual way is to use hooks like `useState`.

Here is my approach for doing what your trying to do, the ReactJS way:

```
import "./header.css";
import { useState } from "react";

function Header() {
  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false);

  return (
    <nav>
      <div className="navbar">
        <div className="logo">
          <img src="../../public/images/logo.svg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <ul className={"ul " + (flag ? 'open' : '')}>
          <li>
            <a href="\">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="\">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="\">Classes</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="\">Trainers</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="\">News</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="\">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="btn">
        <button>Book Class</button>
      </div>
      <div className="menu">
        <i className={"ri-menu-line menu-icon " + (flag ? 'bx-x' : '')} onClick={() => setFlag((prevVal) => !prevVal)}></i>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

What this does is to keep track of things using the state variable `flag` which is a `boolean` that is switched when the `i` element is clicked.
When that state variable is `true`, the target elements' `className` value is changed to include the extra class.

This is just a raw example, there are better ways to set `className` than things like: `"ul " + (flag ? 'open' : '')`

Comment: thnk you very much I initially tried this by react state hook useState but it was not quit giving approoriate results